# Prove/disprove that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

> Prove or disprove that the set $(V,\oplus,\odot)$ with the given operations $\oplus,\odot$ form a vector space $V$ over the respective field $(\mathbb{K},+,\cdot)$:
>   a) Let $V$ be equal to the set of all real numbers greater than zero, and $\mathbb{K}$ the field of real numbers, $(V=\mathbb{R}_{>0} \text{ and } \mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R})$ and apply $x\oplus y := x\cdot y$ and $c\odot x := x^c$

As $V,\mathbb{K}\in \mathbb{R}$ what axioms exactly do I need to show? I know that I always need to show that $(V,\oplus)$ is closed under $\oplus$. However I'm not sure what other axioms are required in order to prove the statement and which axioms I don't need to show again, because they already apply to $\mathbb{R}$ and therfore to $V$ and $\mathbb{K}$

Comment: check all of the vector conditions: community, associativity, scalar multiplication, additive identity, scalar identity, additive inverse, scalar associativity, distributivity

Comment: You definition of $\;V\;$ *and* $\;\Bbb K\;$ isn't clear to me: who is "the set of all real numbers greater than zero"? I think this is $\;V\;$ ...but then what is $\;\Bbb K\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio I think $V=\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}_{>0}$

Comment: @Doesbaddel: No, $\mathbb{K}$ cannot be the positive reals, because $\mathbb{K}$ must be a field. $V$ is the positive reals, and $\mathbb{K}$ is *all* reals.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yeah that makes a lot more sense, thank you!

Comment: Do I need to show, that the neutral, inverse element from $(\mathbb{K},+)\in V$ ?

Comment: Is that a requirement to be a vector space?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069866/why-is-the-set-of-all-positive-real-numbers-with-addition-defined-by-x-y-xy

Comment: I thought so. In our lecture, we defined that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$, if $(V,\oplus)$ is an abelian group and if community, associativity, scalar multiplication, additive identity, scalar identity, additive inverse, scalar associativity, distributivity will be fulfilled.

Comment: First, "commutativity", not "community". Second, "additive identity" is for $(V,\oplus)$, so what does the neutral element of $\mathbb{K}$ have to do with anything? Look carefully at your definition of vector space, and I'll bet you that the **only** element of $\mathbb{K}$ that is mentioned explicitly is the *multiplicative identity*, $1$, and it's about what its effect is when you multiply it by a vector, not about whether it is in $V$ or not. There is no part of the definition of a vector space that tells you anything about what the neutral element of $\mathbb{K}$ does.

Comment: I will have a close look at it tomorrow. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'll add an example of one of the axioms you need to verify.  $\forall \alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R \forall x \in \Bbb R_{\gt 0}~\alpha \odot (\beta \odot x) = (\alpha \beta) \odot x$.

Comment: I tried to do the task and I found out that V is a vectorspace, is that right?